# Array loses its contents after exiting xmlhttpRequest

Tags: javascript, arrays, gm-xmlhttprequest

I know that is a stupid question but i want to ask how i can save content to an array inside a xmlhttpRequest and use them after.

```
onlinestatus = new Array(count);
for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.website.com/player/' + player[i] + '/details.php',
        onload: function(responseDetails) {
            buddypage = jQuery(responseDetails.responseText);
            online = jQuery("span#OnlineStatus", buddypage);
            onlinestatus[i] = online.text();
        }
    });
    GM_log("Current: " + onlinestatus[i]);
}​
```

Comment: @dbaseman. ajax, ajax...

Comment: @gdoron yes, I missed that *GM_log* is outside of the callback.

Comment: For the `!@#$ing` ∞th time, the "A" in "ajax" stands for "asynchronous." Code which depends on the data recieved must be moved into the callback. End of story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things will stop this working: the web request will be asynchronous, and the values will all be stored in the same location in the array.

Here's the order things will happen, assuming count = 2:

1. Set `i = 0`
2. Check, `i < count`, is true, continue for loop
3. Web request A starts
4. Print `result[0]`
5. Set `i = 1`
6. Check, `i < count`, is true, continue for loop
7. Web request B starts
8. Print `result[1]`
9. Set `i = 2`
10. Check, `i < count`, is false, exit for loop
11. ... time passes ...
12. Web request A completes, sets `result[i]`, so set `result[2] = "foo"`
13. Web request B completes, sets `result[i]`, so set `result[2] = "bar"`

That means that the result array ends up as `[undefined, undefined, "bar"]`. The last value of the array could be foo or bar, depending on which web request finishes first. Either way, by the time the web requests complete, `i` will have already been set to the wrong value, and the results will have already been logged, so it will look like the results array is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You should know that ajax request returns at some unknown time in the future.
You can use the array only in the callback of the ajax request.

*AJAX- **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML*